# How can I manually add activity to Bugzilla?

Tags: perl, bugzilla

I am making a simple time sheet for which people can register times 
worked on a bug real quickly.

But the hours added to the bugs_activity table are not noticed 
anywhere.

here is a simple made up line

```
Bugzilla::Bug::LogActivityEntry(1, 'work_time', 0, 66, 1, '2010-01-12 14:44:44');
```

Pretty much, add 66 hours to bug 1, work time.  This executes like I would expect but does nothing else.  I also need to send e-mails and add comments.  I can't find anything on using Bug.pm or LogActivityEntry API.

Is this a huge undertaking or what ?

What I would need is what else is required of me, this is just a batch job that runs when the user presses submit and this info can be on many bugs.  I know how to get the bugs, user and such, just not registering the hours, I need the final item.  This can be almost as rough as the example above.

I am using Bugzilla 3.4.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time worked is kept in longdescs table - the table with comments. Hours worked in fact is a property of a comment. (I also think it's weird.)

bugs_activity table that you're modifying is the table for the history of changes, I bet you can see the result of your call on the "bug activity" page. But it does not change the state of the bug.

Hope this helps.
Igor

Comment: This helped.  Now I need to find out how to send mail to everyone involved with the bug.  Do you know that ?

Comment: Not out of the top of my head. I would look into the sources, say, whine.pl script.